# Push changes in two stages, but resulting in a single commit in branch master

Tags: git

**The way I usually work**

I have a web server in production. When I write some changes to the code, I do it locally on a test host. Once I am happy with the changes, I commit and push to the server. Fine.

**Question**

The problem I have is that I want to implement a feature that requires complicated modifications of the database linked to the website, thus forcing me to make the changes in several steps. I need to:

- Push some changes to the server
- Modify the database on the server
- Push some other changes to the server

How can I push the changes with git in two steps as shown above, but such that I would only have a single commit in branch master?

Comment: *How can I push the changes with git in two steps as shown above, but such that I would only have a single commit in branch master?* You can't. Once you push multiple commits to another repo, they can't magically become one.

Comment: OK, but can't you make a branch with two commits, that you then merge with branch master in a way that they appear as a single commit in master?

Comment: Merging != squashing.